# Reading sling:OsgiConfig into @ObjectClassDefinition

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, apache-felix, sling

We have a OSGI Service (using R7 DS annotation). We are using OCD as innerclass within the service.

Also, we would like the component to read properties from the predefined sling:osgiconfig nodes in JCR.

Configuration policy is defined as required.

When the component/service load it goes into a "no config" state.

Need help to read these configs from sling:osgiCongig nodes.

Comment: The component remains in "no config" state even though there is sling:osgiconfig for the corresponding PID present in JCR ... kindly help

Comment: Where is your configuration saved? Could be a run mode mismatch between the instance and the location of the `sling:OsgiConfig` node. If you define the nodes via a CRX package, are you sure the filters include them? Do you see them in CRXDE?

Answer (score 0):

The `sling:OsgiConfig` configurations should be defined with the Service implementation class name that's supposed to consume the OCD configurations, and not with the OCD name.

OCDs are basically interfaces that can have multiple implementations. Hence the sling:OsgiConfig nodes have to be defined with the service implementation class name. For example let's say you have a `SampleServiceImpl.class` defining a `SampleOCDConfig.class` as below:

```
@Component(service = SampleService.class)
@Designate(ocd = SampleServiceImpl.Config.class)
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    public static final String DEFAULT_CUSTOM_CONFIG = "default configuration value";

    @ObjectClassDefinition(name = "Sample OCD Configuration")
    @interface Config {

        @AttributeDefinition(name = "The custom config", defaultValue = DEFAULT_CUSTOM_CONFIG)
        String custom_config() default DEFAULT_CUSTOM_CONFIG;

    }
...
```

Now when you define the configurations for above setup, you must define it like below:

```
/apps/your_project/config/your.sample.service.package.path.SampleServiceImpl.xml
```

with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    custom.config="default configuration value" />
```

Comment: I understand that. We have coded it the same way. The problem is that when the service start it never finds the config and goes into a "no config" state.

Comment: However, if we simply configure the component, component is pre-populated with the same set of configs defined under /apps/*/config. Once we save for it reflects in service. I am trying to figure out why service never finds the config under /apps/*/config folder and goes into a no-config state... kindly help ...

Comment: That's quite strange. It works for me if implemented as per the sample provided above. Can you share your code snippet for further analysis?

Comment: When we open the configuration we get the sling:osgiconfig values ... but on component activation we get a blank OCD .... Which is causing issue...